# GCP's Vertex AI(AI Platform) PipelineServiceClient gives unimplemented error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When trying to list pipelines with `PipelineServiceClient` `list_pipeline_jobs` method as given [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.pipeline_service.PipelineServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_pipeline_service_PipelineServiceClient_list_pipeline_jobs), I get the following error:

```
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
details = "Received http2 header with status: 404"
...
```

How is the API unimplemented, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we are missing here:

1. We need to initialize PipelineServiceClient with client options with the correct endpoint. List of endpoints are given [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest). Also it should be in the format of `endpoint:port`
2. We need to give the correct request to the `list_pipeline_jobs`.

Example: for `asia-south1` region, we would write a call like this:

```
import google.cloud.aiplatform as aip
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions

aip.init(project='<PROJECT_NAME>',
         staging_bucket='PROJECT_BUCKET',
         location='asia-south1')

options = ClientOptions(
    api_endpoint="asia-south1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443")

cli = aip.gapic.PipelineServiceClient(client_options=options)

parent = cli.common_location_path(project='<PROJECT_NAME>', location='asia-south1')
request = aip.gapic.ListPipelineJobsRequest(
    request=request
)

pipeline_jobs_pager = cli.list_pipeline_jobs(parent=parent) # returns a pager object

for page in pipeline_jobs_pager.pages:
  for pipeline_job in page.pipeline_jobs:
    print(pipeline_job.name)
```

**Note:** `gapic` can be replaced with `v1` or `v1beta1` calls.